# PNAS citation style for chapters in a book series

Tags: publications, citation-style

I am currently trying to format the reference list of my latest article for Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences. Unfortunately, PNAS has its own reference style, and it is minimally documented in the intructions for authors.

> **References.** References must be in PNAS style. *[...]* Include the full title for each cited article. All authors (unless there are more than more than five) should be named in the citation. If there are more than five, list the first author’s name followed by et al. Provide volume and issue numbers for journal articles as applicable; provide DOI numbers if volume/issue numbers are not available. Provide inclusive page ranges for journal articles and book chapters. Provide date of access for online sources. Cite databases in the text or as footnotes.
>   Journal articles are cited as follows:
>
> 10. Neuhaus J-M, Sticher L, Meins F, Jr, Boller T (1991) A short C-terminal sequence is necessary and suf cient for the targeting of chitinases to the plant vacuole. *Proc Natl Acad Sci USA* 88(22):10362–10366.
>
> Use MEDLINE/PubMed abbreviations of journal titles or use the full journal title for any journals not indexed in MEDLINE.
>   Articles or chapters in books are cited as follows:
>
> 14. Hill AVS (1991) HLA associations with malaria in Africa: some implications for MHC evolution. *Molecular Evolution of the Major Histocompatibility Complex*, eds Klein J, Klein D (Springer, Heidelberg), pp 403-420.

I tried to find in published articles an example of a reference for a book chapter in a series of book but couldn't find it.

I have several citations concerned but one of them, to give an example, is the article "Pelagic sedimentation in modern and ancient oceans" by H. Hünecke & R. Henrich, published, in 2011, in pages 215 to 351 of the book *Deep-Sea Sediments* (edited by H. Hünecke & T. Mulde) which is volume 63 of the book series *Developments in Sedimentology* (published by Elsevier).

My understanding is that in APA reference style it would be:

> Hünecke, H., Henrich, R. (2011). Pelagic sedimentation in modern and ancient oceans. In H. Hünecke & T. Mulde (Eds.), *Developments in Sedimentology: Vol. 63. Deep-Sea Sediments* (pp. 215-351). Amsterdam, Netherlands:Elsevier.

In many Elsevier journals, the reference would become:

> Hüneke, H., Henrich, R., 2011. Pelagic sedimentation in modern and ancient oceans. In: Hüneke, H., Mulder, T. (Eds.), Deep-Sea Sediments, Developments in Sedimentology, 63. Elsevier, pp. 215–351.

What would it be in PNAS reference style?

Answer (score 1):

Among other things, on its webpage PNAS supplies [a LaTeX template for authors](http://www.pnas.org/site/authors/latex.xhtml).  This template includes both examples of references and also a BibTeX style file that you can use for preparing references in PNAS style.